# $A*$ finite or infinite? (Set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a question regarding the following:

> If $A$ is a set, then by $A*$ we mean the set of all finite rows of elements of $A$. Now suppose $A$ is finite. How big is $A*$, and how can you see that?

I don't understand why and how $A*$ is finite, since I believe that it can definitely keep going (infinite) because of the Kleene star. 
If I suppose that $A$ is finite, how can I possibly explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^*$ is infinite (unless of course $A=\emptyset$), but that is not the answer you must give. The question is "how" infinite it is, meaning countable or larger.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
So in that case, I guess A* is countably infinite, since A itself is finite. 
Am I correct?

Comment: Well, your argument is no proof, but you are correct.